# need help separating my L/R in to two inputs

Tags: production-audio

ok....so.
My band uses in ear click and backing tracks.  We have mp3 renders of the audio files with just the click panned left and the right just the backing tracks.

My issue is finding an efficient way to split the mp3 track into our mixing board.  In short, our left channel with click goes to in ear transmitter and right channel with backing track goes to PA system.  I have searched for 3.5 to 1/4 cables that would separate the audio but after wasting money it just duplicates the entire rendering into both inputs.  Suggestions on what cables are out there for this application?? Thanks.

example:

1. tablet playing the mp3 file with 3.5 output
   (here is where I have the issue splitting audio left and right)
2. Left signal with click goes to mixing board channel 1, panned all the way left.   Right signal with just track, no click, goes to channel 2 mixing board panned all the way right.
3. Mixer main out Left goes to ear in transmiter.  Mixer main out Right goes to PA system.

   -Andy

Comment: Why don't you just take that stereo signal directly into your mixer, and pan the two sides to 2 channels?

Comment: tried it. it doesn't split the mix. It only pans the entire mix to either the L or R main outs. Pretty sure the split has to be prior to the mixer for this to work they way id like it to.  The 3.5 - (x2)1/4 cable i bought didn't split left and right. It doubled the stereo all together.  Having trouble finding a cable capable of doing what I need.

Comment: Sounds like you have the wrong cable, TRS when you need a properly-configured TRRS. See [CableChick - Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/)

Comment: What is the make and model of the mixer? You wrote that you’ve tried cables that didn’t work, can you be more specific about the cables that didn’t work? Should just be a stereo 3.5mm plug on one end and a split to two 1/4” mono plugs on the other end would work.